# Scripted Jenkinsfile - Multi choice in middle of run

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a scripted pipeline, that look like this:

```
node(){
  stage("test"){
    echo "test"
  }
  stage("two"){
      deployOptions = "one\ntwo\nthree\nfour\nfive"

      def userInput = input(
        id: 'userInput', message: 'pick option', parameters: [
          [$class: 'ChoiceParameterDefinition', choices: deployOptions, description: 'Select deployment', name: 'deploy-pick']
      ])
    echo "you selected: ${userInput}"
  }
  stage("deploy"){
    echo "deploy"
  }
}
```

What happens is that the first stage print "test", the second stage wait for user pick of `list([one,two,three,four,five])`, and after the user pick option, the pipeline run the "deploy" stage.

But what I want now, is instead of picking one option from the deployOptions list, I want to be able to pick multiple options (like extendedChoice in the pre-build parameters).

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I solved it.

I used the `"com.cwctravel.hudson.plugins.extended_choice_parameter.ExtendedChoiceParameterDefinition"` Class.